# How to create custom extension on Magento 2, or module or plugin

Tags: magento2, module, plugin

There are many tutorials available when people start to say: "Here is how to create custom Magento 2 **extension**". And then they start to describe how to create **module**, instead of the extension. So i was confused, is it the same or there is the difference between **module** and **extension**? Then, later on, someone also mentioned **plugins**. Now I'm really confused, because we have 3 different types of additions/enhancers of Magento 2 functionality: **extensions**, **modules**, **plugins**.

The question is, if this all 3 not the same:

1. Then what the technical differences between them?
2. What is possible to accomplish with one of them that not possible with another one. Or what are limitations of all 3 of them by what is possible to do?
3. How installation process differs between those 3 types?

I need to clearly understand this, because I need to decide which one is the best fit for my needs to be selected. Plus would be nice to have links to the tutorials, if they are not the same, to all 3 of them separately.

Thanks for the help.